# Center type vertically in resizable div

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment, resizable

I know this has been answered a thousand times but nothing I found seems to work. I have full width picture that resizes with navigator window. Then I have a box in the center with text inside. Image box and type are resizing as expected but I can't seem to make the type centered with multiple lines of text. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="block-full">
    <div class="info-box-full">
        <div class="slide-info">
            <span><?php echo $ss_slide_post_title?><br><?php echo $ss_slide_post_desc;?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<img src="<?php echo $image_link[0];?>" alt="">
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.block-full {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 45%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.info-box-full {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    height: 26%;
    margin-left: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 37%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.slide-info {
    font-size: 1vw;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-top: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is style="text-align:center" inside the html tag and that will center all the text inside the tag in accordance to the size of the container, relatively.

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox.

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Quick start: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0 }

figure {
  display: flex;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/urlCI95.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
}

figcaption {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>Vertically centered text.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Editable Demo: [http://jsbin.com/fagopu/2](http://jsbin.com/fagopu/2/edit?html,css,output)